# Regulating multithreaded access to python list (boost)

Tags: c++, python, multithreading, boost, locking

a few weeks ago I asked another question related to passing a reference of a list from python to c++ with boost. This Question has been answered well and detailed. The answer also mentioned the use of GIL for locking certain Threads. My Problem now is, that I don't really understand how to use it correctly, because in my code, it crashes the application.

First I want to explain what it is, I want to do:

I have a list in python being passed to c++, to fill it, and render from its contents. The idea behind it is, to change the rendered contents from python directly by changing the python list. Therefore I need to lock the list so it can't be touched from python while its being filled and executed in the c++ code.
Also I like to have it, that when I change something in the list, but the GIL (I think) is active because its doing something in c++ with the list, it will change right after the lock is released.

What I tried to lock was:

```
PyGILState_STATE lock;
lock = PyGILState_Ensure();
```

and to end it:

```
PyGILState_Release(lock);
```

I'm pretty sure I understood the GIL wrong. But I don't know what went wrong. Thank you for any suggestions

Greetings
Chris

Comment: why not just use two separate buffer ? One which is written by python and read by c++ and the other one written by c++ and read by python (and a memcopy each time the c++ function is called to move datas).

Comment: I have to do it that way...